# Is there a way to modify upload functionality of ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor

I was trying to use the upload feature in ckeditor with kcfinder.

[image]

However, the current functionality of this is that you need to first click the "Send it to the server" button. In order for the image to be uploaded to the server. I wan't it to be remove and when I click the OK button it will upload the image and added to the content automatically no more resizing or whatsoever. Is there anyway to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter what ckeditor does on [fileUploadRequest](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-fileUploadRequest) and [fileUploadResponse](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-fileUploadResponse). An example of how to use these two responses is like:

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
<script>
    var ck = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    ck.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function(evt) {
         //custom code to remove image
         //and upload content here
    });
</script>
```